# Creating a PAM function with Matlab

Tags: matlab

So I need to make a function that will be called as `function [t, pulse] = PAM (array)`. My function should have a result like this when I use `array = [1 0.3 0.8 0.6]`, which **array is the width of my digital pulsing signal**.

[image: result]

Comment: Download the book linked at the bottom of the page here: https://sethares.engr.wisc.edu/telebreak.html and read chapter 8.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  I'd recommend what MBaz suggests. Chapter 8 seems to have a good exposition of how to convert [between bits and symblos.](http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~sethares/telebreak.pdf) I don't think MBaz is either Rick or Bill. (MBaz, if you are, Hi!).

Comment: @PeterK. I'm neither :-) I'm just a big fan of their books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

```
function [t, pulse] = PAM (array)
  syms t
  u(t) = heaviside(t);
  pulse = array(1)*u(t);
  
  for i = [2:length(array)]
    if array(i) > array(i - 1)
      pulse += abs(array(i-1)-array(i)).*u(t - (i-1));
    else 
      pulse -= (array(i-1)-array(i)).*u(t-(i-1));
    endif
  endfor
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier and faster to use the kron function as below

```
function [t, pulse] = pam(array,B,fs)

pulse=kron(array,ones(1,fs/B));
t=(0:length(pulse)-1)/fs;
```

where fs is the sampling frequency and B is the bandwidth of the pulse.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the repelem() function.